# Best way to measure communication overhead in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, networking, cryptography, overhead

Imagine that you have an encryption algorithm that requires you to send additional information to the receiver over the network (not necessary a key as by itself you cannot decrypt the message)

What would be the best way to measure this "overhead"?

Example:

Say what you are sending is:

AdditionalInfo = ['a'  '@'   233  52]

other times it can be shorter/longer depends on the message being encrypted

Comment: Measure? Surely you can calculate it from first principles? From your knowledge of the algorithm?

Comment: The overhead dynamically changes with the text being encrypted what I'm asking about is say i have this: AdditionalInfo = ['a' '@' 233 52] in what way/unit i can define that overhead. For example is it 8bit*number of characters or such

Comment: The plaintext has a length in bytes and the overhead has a length in bytes. If you can generate the overhead from code you can calculate it from code for a given plaintext. The efficiency is given by `payload/gross`.